# Free hand draw on LaTeX Presentations Fullscreen

Tags: pdf, latex, fullscreen, presentations, annotations

I use LaTeX beamer presentation to teach students. My teaching style involves using the PDF free hand writing tool and making annotations on the presentation using a drawing tablet. The problem is that acrobat reader disables the annotation tool bar when you go into fullscreen. I have searched for days, but there doesn't seem to be a way to annotate PDFs in full screen, but I can only annotate the PDF in standard maximized view.

An alternative is powerpoint presentation, which allows you to annotate in full screen, but the most recent power point versions don't save the annotations. If you annotated a slide, and then move to the next one, all annotations get deleted. Since the course I teach has a lot of statistical content, LaTeX presentations are ideal.

My question: Does anyone know how to annotate a presentation made from LaTeX beamer in full screen? Are they are any presentation apps that allows you to do that?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Using the Reader mode (Ctrl+H) might give you some more screen space while using a window. I'm not sure how you'd hide the "document tabs" though.

Comment: @RobHyndman I am using a mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Okular (https://okular.kde.org/) or Notability (http://gingerlabs.com/)

Comment: It looks like notability should do the trick. Its not too expensive either. Has anyone tried using Notability to annotate PDFs in full screen. I use a drawing tablet connect to my mac.

Answer (score 1):

Other great options to draw on the screen (not restricted to PDFs in fullscreen), are Epic Pen (for Windows) or Gromit-MPX (for GNU/Linux). The pro version of Epic Pen enables features such as drawing arrows, straight lines, rectangles and even text.